# How do I download macOS Monterey on unsupported Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, install, mac-appstore

My Macbook Pro is running macOS Big Sur 11.7.

I'm trying to find a legitimate way, via terminal or app store or some other 'Apple' way (no third-party websites, tools, or apps) to download macOS 12 on my unsupported Macbook.

Please note that I am **not** trying to install it on my unsupported MBP - I just want the Installer.app of Monterey to be in my Applications folder or something.

***What I have tried:***

I tried using the Terminal command ([article source](https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/13/how-download-full-macos-installer-terminal/)) `softwareupdate --list-full-installers` and `softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version x.x.x` - however it does not list Monterey. I tried forcing the command by putting the version explicitly even though it wasn't listed by doing this:

```
softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 12.0.1
```

But the terminal throws an error: "Install failed with error: Update not found"

Then I tried the normal method of going to [Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683), clicking the App Store Link, opening in App Store, and clicking the 'Get' button - which opens up Software Update, which thereafter throws another similar "Update not found" error like Terminal.

Comment: just curious, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Ant If you really must know, I'm trying to install it in VMware. I see Ventura is about to be released this month, so I'll wait for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always, Mr Macintosh has the reliable database of links into Apple's CDN.

https://mrmacintosh.com/macos-12-monterey-full-installer-database-download-directly-from-apple/

Comment: Thank you so much. For some reason this was not appearing in my search results - I was only getting solutions on how to install macOS 12 on an unsupported mac with a bunch of different tools.